# Why are reputation changes in the header sometimes in blue and other times in green?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Earlier today I got a blue notification about rep changes:

[image: blue reputation change]

And just now I got the regular green notification:

[image: green reputation change]

Is there a distinction between the two colors? I notice that the blue counter has a different offset (I can see more of the star, for example). Perhaps this is an A/B test?

Comment: I saw that one too, today. I thought it was for awarded bounty. I didn't pay too much attention to the number itself, just the color.

Comment: It was a bug that's already been fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340181/reputation-changes-showing-with-blue-background

Comment: @animuson sigh, I never think to check on meta.SE instead of meta.SO. Still no way for cross-site dupe closing, right?

Comment: I thought it was related to the hats event, and kind of liked the blue. Too bad it was a bug.

Comment: I liked the blue too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was a bug which has since been fixed.

As noted by [animuson♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392105/why-are-reputation-changes-in-the-header-sometimes-in-blue-and-other-times-in-gr/392106#comment744687_392105) this was [answered at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340197/178816):

> Tiny bug there with a variable rename. Our variable literally named @green was coming out blue. CSS  - [Aaron Shekey♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey)

Comment: gotta love CSS!